# change the layout of jquery-steps plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I'm trying to reconfigure the layout of the jquery-steps plugin. I suppose it's fairly simple task.. but I can't figure it myself. 
[I would like to swap actions div and the steps div (showed in this picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT1BI.jpg). So that actions are on top and steps at the bottom.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us what have you tried to do?

Comment: hi @AlessioCantarella. I tried to go through **jquery.steps.js** to see how the template is build, but i couldn't figure it out where the template is actually put together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery Steps' Wizard *Basic Demo*, you could use jQuery to move the items in your desired order (actions, content, steps):

```
$(function() {
    $("#wizard > .content").appendTo("#wizard");
    $("#wizard > .steps").appendTo("#wizard");
});
```

**UPDATE:** after the latest update of jQuery Steps' website, *Basic Demo* was replaced with [*Basic Example*](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples), which is similar, but its `id` changed to `example-basic`, so you need the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#example-basic > .content").appendTo("#example-basic");
    $("#example-basic > .steps").appendTo("#example-basic");
});
```

Comment: that's great! nice and simple solution. much appreciated!

Comment: @AlessioCantarella this was very helpful because I wanted my Steps section separated from the Wizard, but by any chance do you know if there is a way to specifically move the Previous button to the left side of the actions container?

Comment: @BlakeRivell of course you can do it with jQuery, e.g. in *Basic Example*: `$("#example-basic > .actions > ul").css("width", "100%");
$("#example-basic > .actions > ul > li:eq(0)").css("float", "left");
$("#example-basic > .actions > ul > li:eq(1)").css("float", "right");`

Comment: @AlessioCantarella thanks! The example I am really trying to replicate is the Basic Form example and for some reason I had to add .wizard to the chain like this:  $("#example-form > .wizard .actions > ul > li:eq(0)").css("float", "left");

Comment: @AlessioCantarella in regards to this actual post, I thought it was the answer to what I am currently trying to do but I don't think it is. Do you know if there is a way to move the steps away from the wizard? For example lets say I have a <div id="wizSteps"> at the very top of my page, but the wizard is somewhere else on the page like in another div below. Can I output the steps into the wizSteps div instead of on top of the wizard which is the default?

Comment: @BlakeRivell you should provide me a JSFiddle example with your code.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ypsg9fwk/ (Please see the section that says: I would like the steps to go here instead...)